# Get open graph data from a link

Tags: python, reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We want to get the open graph image tag metadata from any URL. Is it possible to get the open graph image metadata from any URL provided in python or react.
This is the implementation I am thinking of

```
timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=settings.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECS)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url, timeout=timeout) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            response_data = await response.text()
                parser = BeautifulSoup(response_data, "html.parser")
                meta_tags = parser.find_all("meta", {"property": "og:image"})
                if meta_tags:
                    img_url = meta_tags[0].get("content")
```

Comment: Please send us a summary of the code you've done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated the description what i have implemented currently